# ASP.NET MVC 3 #randomstring showing up in URLs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and every page I go to the url will have stuff like #.TpjRmN6XudB appended to. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: What references have you got added? (via Nuget or otherwise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably turned cookieless session state to on.

Check your application **web.config** for

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true"/>
```

and change to

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false"/>
```

Comment: Corrected if for the future someone ;)